# Cycle2 play after being paused

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I'm using cycle 2 and am having trouble getting cycle to start again. I have a group of divs. One of which is wrapping a video and the other two have images. My parent wrapper has the following:

```
<div id="hero-wrapper" class="cycle-slideshow"
   data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
   data-cycle-timeout="0"
   data-cycle-prev="#prev"
   data-cycle-next="#next"
   data-cycle-slides="> div"
   >
```

I have some js to bind the end of the video:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#hero-video_html5_api").bind("ended", function() {
 $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('next');
```

This does call the next slide after the video plays. However, it does not continue to cycle. It stops here. I tried adding 'reinit', 'resume', etc. However, none of those seem to make the slideshow continue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Set `data-cycle-paused` to true
- Set `data-cycle-timeout` to 5000 or some other reasonable value
- *May be* set `data-cycle-loop` to 1 so that it stops after last slide

This will create the slideshow in paused state on page load. You can resume it when necessary using `.cycle("resume")` in which case the timeout and loop settings will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle({
  continueAuto: true 
});
```